# Mono for Android binding project namespace not visible

Tags: xamarin.android, java-binding

I made a Java Binding Project for my Mono Android project.
I added Google Analytics v2 jar and made it build correctly.

I also referenced the binding project in my app project (project reference) and it shows at my references.
Only, visual studio doesn't recognise the namespace "Com.Google.Analytics.Tracking.Android".
When I inspect the reference in Object browser, it has this namespace and I can also find the class 'EasyTracker' within this namespace.

Also just adding the release build .dll as a reference doesn't work.

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

The clue was to include the Jar in my project as AndroidJavaLibrary. Hope this helps anyone running into this thread.